# jquery scale to centre/center scaling without using show/hide/toggle

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a way to centre scale elements using jquery without having the element hide/show/toggle the element.

The code below will scale to centre an object to 150% then return it to 100% (hide scale to 150% then hide it). I just want it to **stay** at 150%.

```
(this).show("scale", { percent: 150}, 500);
```

I've tried the following:

```
 $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 150}, 500);
 $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 150,origin:'center'}, 500);
 $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 150,origin:'middle'}, 500);
```

But the "origin" para is invalid.

I'm unsure why show/hide/toggle need to be connected to scale and center to.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/LEgMQ/5/

Edited for link with correct answer, see comments below.

Comment: This is not scaling to centre, its scaling to Top Left. check out below. the second one is what i want without it going back to the original size.

http://jsfiddle.net/LEgMQ/3/

Comment: scaling from top left, not to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LEgMQ/5/

that will do it but the box jumps after the effect. weird. it's a [known bug though](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4316) (and where I got the answer). says it's fixed, dunno about this version of jquery though.

Comment: It must switch to absolute while animating and then back to static.